# Preserving variable values within a PHP function

Tags: php

I have a function which I call multiple times within a script.  The value returned from the function will always be the same.  I would rather not execute all the script within the function each time since the returned value is always the same.  I am not using OOP so can't assign it to a object property and do the script in the constructor.

Below is my attempt.  It doesn't work since $status is not set until it later is defined as a static variable.  How can I accomplish my goal?

```
function checkStatus()
{
    if(!isset($status))
    {
        //Do some script to determine $cond
        if($cond) {static $status=0;}
        else {static $status=1;}
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: If the return value is always the same, what is the purpose of the function?

Comment: You need somewhere *outside* of the scope of this function to save the value.  A global variable or a session could work.

Comment: @showdev.  The value will be 0 or 1, but each subsequent time it is called, it will always be the same.

Comment: @RocketHazmat.  I would rather not use a session.  A global variable or a constant is more preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
function checkStatus()
{

  static $status;

  if(!isset($status))
  {

    if (TRUE) // Whatever your truth condition will be
    {
      $status = 1;
    }

    else
    {
      $status = 0;
    }

  }

  return $status;

}
```

Comment: I just came up with this as well, and tested it and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the variable by reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

```
function checkStatus(&$status)
{
    //Do some script to determine $cond
    if($status == 0) { 
      $status=1;
    }
    else {
      $status=0;
    }
  }

$status = 0;
checkStatus($status);
echo $status; //this should display 1;
```